Is it possible to suppress just one tick mark label?
I'm generating a plot and I am trying to figure out how to suppress just one tick-mark label (not the mark -- just the label).
Here's some example code:
x1 <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)
y1 <- runif(n = 100, min = 1, max = 10)
library(rando)
labe <- r_Letters(nchar = 1, n = 100)

test_dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, y1, labe))
test_dat$x1 <- as.numeric(test_dat$x1)
test_dat$y1 <- as.numeric(test_dat$y1)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
g <- ggplot(data = test_dat, aes(x = x1, y = y1))
g <- g + geom_line()
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + expand_limits(x = c(-10, 110), y = c(0, 10))
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 25))
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))
g <- g + geom_label_repel(data = test_dat, aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = labe), 
                         size = 2.0, color = "blue", box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"), 
                         point.padding = unit(0, "lines"))
g

In my real dataset, when I use geom_label_repel to label my points (a subset of my real data; I got lazy in my example), I needed to extend the range of the plot (hence, expand_limits). All of the tick marks are where I'd like them, but the one on the far left (-15 in my example) is unphysical and I'd like to remove just that one.
I can figure out how to suppress all the tick marks and all the labels, but that's not what I'm after -- I want to leave the tick marks as they are, but just remove the label on the one that's furthest left.
Any thoughts?

IMHO there's nothing wrong with leaving a tic&label in a region where data is nonexistent or impossible.  You may be overthinking this.

I've received beatings before for such things. It's in a region that would make the data seem unphysical (negative values for mass), and I wanted to squash the question before anyone said anything.

One approach could be to manually adjust your break labels using a formula that outputs a blank at the -15 label, but otherwise leaves it alone.
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 25),
                            labels = ~if_else(.x == -15, "", as.character(.x))) 



Why did you set expand_limits in the first place if you don't want that region displayed?   My approach, at least if you only want to suppress a label at one end or the other of the domain, would be not to plot that area in the first place.
Further, I suspect Ed. Tufte would frown angrily if you wanted to hide a tic label in the middle of the domain (or range) of a graph.

In my original data, I labeled my points (as I did here), but with that data, I needed just a bit of extra room for them to not be cut off. So that region isn't meaningful -- it's just there to provide space. None of the actual data is in that part of the graph (it would be terrible if it were!).
